# Need to delete values to left of cell if Same Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

How do I delete cells to the left of my latest value?

For example- In the attached image I want to have only the value in column E for row 3, only the value in column D for row 5 & 6, only the value in column C for row 8.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: "Deleting" sounds like VBA. Would it suffice to simply display the desired value in column F or into a new column A?

Comment: That might work. But I am not too sure how to do that.

How would we go about doing this in VBA? I have no experience with VBA so i would have to look into that

Comment: Let me clarify. If you want to Delete stuff, then you'll need VBA. But if you do NOT need to delete but simply display the value elsewhere (such as in column F), then you can use an OFFSET formula combined with MATCH and MAX to display the last value in each row.

Comment: I am familiar with Match and Max. How do I combine that with Offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wanting to display the last value of each row in Column F, then input this formula into column F:

```
=OFFSET(A2,0,MATCH(MAX(A2:E2)+1,A2:E2,1)-1)
```

I'm sure there are several ways to accomplish this, and this is one such method.

**----------------EDIT -----------------**

Based on your comment, looking for the column number of the latest value, then the easiest method is simply using a COUNTA formula, provided you have no gaps in your data.

```
=COUNTA(A2:E2)
```

[image]

**---------------EDIT 2 ----------------**

If you indeed have gaps, then you can use this formula to obtain the last column with data:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A2:E2)/((A2:E2<>"")),1)
```

Comment: Thank you

Would it be possible to find the column number for the last value? I think that would be more useful in this instance.

Comment: @UCMan I made some edits based on the above comment.

Comment: @UCMan if you find the answer useful, please accept it as the answer to your question by clicking the tick button on the top left of the answer.